# How to find WCF host/client by ServiceContract in a huge solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have a really big VS2010 solution which is completely new to me and when debugging I often need to find a host/client of some particular ServiceContract. Is that possible? Can ReSharper help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Yes Exactly you can use `Resharper` to `find your contract` easily. (With just click)

2 You can also install `Productivity Tool`, she offers good functionalities.

Link : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef

3 You can also use `Call Hierrachy`  on your right click in Visual Studion

Comment: thanks for answering my newbie question)

Comment: I'am happy to help you Lonelyass